# Centrar un JPanel dentro de otro

Tags: java

necesito ayuda para centrar tres JPanel dentro de otro JPanel, en cada JPanel hay tres botones que estan posicionados con boxlayout para tenerlos agrupados ya que estoy creando un juego de tres en raya.El resultado que me da es los tres jpanel juntos en el centro arriba del jpanel principal.

He probado con borderLayout pero no me lo centra.

Algun consejo?

Comment: Tres paneles... tres botones... alineados ¿cómo?; tu descripción es insuficiente.

Comment: tengo cuatro paneles un panel que es el principal en el que tiene tres paneles , en cada panel tengo tres botones que estan alineados horizontalmente como si fuera el juego de tres en raya, ahora los tres paneles estan formando un cuadrado con trres lineas de tres botones alineados horizontalmente, quiero consejos de como puedo mover ese cuadrado o esos paneles para ubicarlo en el centro